# ¿Qué actitud es adecuada para estimular la buena calidad de preguntas y respuestas?

Tags: discusión, votos, convenciones-sociales

Desde la apertura del sitio he estado al margen de la publicación, desarrollo y contenido de las diferentes preguntas y respuestas formuladas acá. He notado una actitud algo extraña, casi negativa en parte de la comunidad.

Inicialmente se publicaron preguntas traducidas directamente desde SOen y, para mi sorpresa, vi el malestar de compañeros que, expresaron su disconformidad con comentarios como "No debe hacer eso, lo hace para ganar reputación". Yo me preguntaba, ¿la pregunta aporta contenido valioso para futuros usuarios? Yo creo que sí. Bueno, de pronto no estoy comprendiendo la intensión del sitio, seguiré al margen. Ahora resulta que, desde hace un par de días me vienen votando negativo diferentes preguntas y respuestas. Yo me decía de nuevo, -bueno, tal vez hice mal en hacer un aporte traducido, pero ¿cómo saberlo si ni siquiera publican un comentario que ayude a mejorar la respuesta?

Hoy, por ejemplo, investigué por horas una [posible solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/302/select2-aurelia-io/599#599) que me parecía alcanzable, y una vez publicada, lo que me topo son con más votos negativos sin comentarios; ¿qué está pasando?, ¿acaso es tan evidente mi error que no hace falta que me lo digan? El sitio es estricto, tal parece. Este comportamiento, específicamente, me llama la atención, ya que soy usuario de SO.en desde hace 3 años y medio, y al menos, en ese tiempo, nunca tuve tal negatividad de los demás usuarios.

Mi conclusión es que, el voto negativo ayuda al mejoramiento, al enriquecimiento de contenido de calidad, pero también se debe señarlar un norte, porque si usted vota negativo es porque tiene un argumento que pueda colaborar a su mejoramiento. Un comentario no solo ayuda al publicador a mejorar, sino que también mantiene una comunidad con una actitud agradable.

Gracias!

Comment: Estoy contigo, existe toda una serie de negativismo con respecto a las migraciones desde SO, yo también prefiero mantenerme al margen. Con respecto a los votos negativos también es algo que yo he notado, solo -1 sin algún comentario que ayude a mejorar el post original. Algo anda mal en la comunidad

Answer (score 1):

La actitud adecuada me parece tal como lo sugieres, votar y cuando se vote negativo dejar un comentario. Sólo que hay tener paciencia y seguir promoviendo una "buena actitud".

Paciencia porque los votos usualmente los dan quienes conocen de los temas que se abarcan en la publicación y porque el sitio está posicionándose poco a poco.

Por cierto, sobre la publicación indicada como [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/302/select2-aurelia-io/599#599), de acuerdo a su [línea de tiempo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/599/timeline) el 7 de diciembre obtuvo un voto positivo y un voto negativo, y del 8 de diciembre 2015 al 7 de octubre de 2016, a lo largo de 10 meses la respuesta ha tenido 5 votos positivos. Si no lo has hecho aún, comparte el enlace a la misma con quienes sabes que conocen o interesados en conocer del tema.

Relacionado

- [¿Cuál es la conducta esperada de los usuarios?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) (artículo de ayuda)
- [Compórtate bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)
- [¿Seria bueno implementar un sistema de referencias para invitar a nuevos usuarios a SO-es?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/869/seria-bueno-implementar-un-sistema-de-referencias-para-invitar-a-nuevos-usuario?noredirect=1&lq=1)